# Variable scoping in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

Here is my attempt to manipulate the value of q for the PDF function. Whenever I use the manipulate function, nothing happens to the output. Can anyone explain why?

[image: my code for the manipulate function]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many code errors, such as the error in defining a function `G[x_]=` instead of `G[x_]:=`, the fact that `sigma` cannot have a value (because `q` is not assigned), missing semicolons, and much more.

I presume you're lifting my code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181852/normal-distribution-plot-construction/181859#181859).

Anyway, here is your answer:

```
Manipulate[
 Integrate[
  PDF[
      NormalDistribution[0, -q Log[2, q] - (1 - q) Log[2, 1 - q]], x], 
  {x, 0, 1}], 
  {q, .1, .3}]
```

Comment: Yes, I was the one who asked the previous question as well.

Comment: ...and never accepted my previous answer.

Comment: I just recently made an account.

Answer (score 1):

You have a variable scoping problem. The global `q` that appears in your definition of `sigma` is not the same as the local `q` that appears in your `Manipulate` expression. One way to fix it is:

```
sigma[q_] := -q Log2[q] - (1 - q) Log2[1 - q]
g[q_][x_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[0, sigma[q]], x]
Manipulate[g[q][x], {q, .0001, 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Manipulate` doesn't "see" the `q` term in the argument.

To fix this use

```
Manipulate[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, sigma], x] /. q -> Q, {Q, 0, 1}]
```

Or make `sigma` a function of `q` as

```
sigma[q_] := -q Log[2, q] - (1 - q) Log[2, 1 - q]
Manipulate[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, sigma[q]], x], {q, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: I made this change. It does work. However, part of the input is to integrate the PDF function G[x]. It does not make the change in Out[54] whenever I manipulate q. Any ideas?